# Need to add selected items using jquery

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have two(named as box1,box2) multiple selected forms and two buttons add/remove in between as designed.Box1 one will have items a,b,c,d,e with values 1,2,3,4,5.I have written the code for adding and removing.Now when i add a,b,c,d to box2 from box1 then i need to get the sum of all the items to be displayed i.e 10, when i remove from box2 one item i.e b then it should show me 8.I want to do it using jquery and css.Kindly help me out or any tutorials are encouraged.I am just a beginner so help me out.thank you :)

I tried this

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#btn-add').click(function(){
        $('#select-from option:selected').each( function() {
                $('#select-to').append("<option value='"+$(this).val()+"'>"+$(this).text()+"</option>");

        });
    });
    $('#btn-remove').click(function(){
        $('#select-to option:selected').each( function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    });

});
</script>


</head>
<body>
<form>
  <fieldset>

    <select name="selectfrom" id="select-from" multiple size="5">
      <option value="1">Item 1</option>
      <option value="2">Item 2</option>
      <option value="3">Item 3</option>
      <option value="4">Item 4</option>
    </select>

    <a href="JavaScript:void(0);" id="btn-add">Add &raquo;</a>
    <a href="JavaScript:void(0);" id="btn-remove">&laquo; Remove</a>

    <select name="selectto" id="select-to" multiple size="5">

    </select>

  </fieldset>
```

Comment: Hey,please check my question once again..i uploaded the code that i tried

Comment: @user1906431. Do you check the answers

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand correctly, but since you know how to copy element, then after doing it (from box1 and box2) take all elements from box2 using jQuery and use `each` method to parse value of each `<option>`. If you define a variable before ie. `var sum = 0;` and then add values to it. You can then display a sum

-- alternatively you can add value while copying and change the sum of options' values straight away

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/uQHx7/) of what I think you mean

NOTE: I removed the `JavaScript:` pseudo protocol from your links and added e.preventDefault()

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var val1 = 0;

    $('#btn-add').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#select-from option:selected').each( function() {
           val1 += parseInt($(this).val(),10);
           $('#select-to').append("<option value='"+$(this).val()+"'>"+$(this).text()+"</option>");

        });
        $("#val1").html(val1);
    });
    $('#btn-remove').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#select-to option:selected').each( function() {
           val1 -= parseInt($(this).val(),10);                
            $(this).remove();
        });
        $("#val1").html(val1);
    });

});
```

Comment: i dont know but i already checked his code same as you did but click event wasn't worked..

Comment: Works for me - I changed the href to "#"

Comment: @mplungjan hey,what i mean is the total sum of all the items that i select in select-to form , and i remove something then the sum should decrease and display...hope you got it

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to count the values of the option added in the select box 2 means this will help you. [DEmo](http://jsfiddle.net/T7bRc/)

```
<a href="JavaScript:void(0);" id="btn-count">&laquo; Count</a>  

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#btn-add').click(function(){
        $('#select-from option:selected').each( function() {
                $('#select-to').append("<option value='"+$(this).val()+"'>"+$(this).text()+"</option>");

        });
    });
    $('#btn-remove').click(function(){
        $('#select-to option:selected').each( function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    });


    $('#btn-count').click(function(){
       var a =0;
         $('#select-to option').each( function() {
            a = a+ parseInt($(this).val());           
         });
         alert(a);
     });   
});
```